# PANDAS Finding the exact word and before word in a column of string and append that new column in python (pandas) column

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas

**Find the target word and the before word in col_a and append  matched string in col_b_PY and col_c_LG columns**

```
    This code i have tried to achive this functionality but not able to 
get the expected output. if any help appreciated
Here is the below code i approach with regular expressions:

df[''col_b_PY']=df.col_a.str.contains(r"(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+) 
{0,1}PY")

df.col_a.str.extract(r"(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){0,1}PY",expand=True)
```

**Dataframe looks like this**

```
col_a

Python PY is a general-purpose language LG

Programming language LG in Python PY 

Its easier LG to understand  PY

The syntax of the language LG is clean PY
```

**Desired output:**

```
col_a                                       col_b_PY      col_c_LG
Python PY is a general-purpose language LG  Python PY     language LG

Programming language LG in Python PY        Python PY     language LG

Its easier LG to understand  PY            understand PY easier LG

The syntax of the language LG is clean PY   clean  PY     language LG
```

Comment: Maybe `df['col_b_PY'] = df['col_a'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+PY)\b')` and `df['col_c_LG'] = df['col_a'].str.extract(r'([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+LG)\b')`

Comment: Many Thanks! @Wiktor Stribizew Spent a lot of time on this to find out

Comment: I added an answer with explanation. Note that a capturing group is necessary for `extract` to really extract the string, it only extracts a *captured* substring.

Comment: `Col_a`
          `Python PY is a general purpose PY language LG`
**in col_a contains PY is two times i need  to capture python py and purpose py
our regex paterrn capturing only one time**
          `output`
          `Python PY purpose PY`

Comment: Ok, it is easy to fix with `extractall`, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
df['col_b_PY'] = df['col_a'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+PY)\b")
df['col_c_LG'] = df['col_a'].str.extract(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+LG)\b")
```

Or, to extract all matches and join them with a space:

```
df['col_b_PY'] = df['col_a'].str.extractall(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+PY)\b").unstack().apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
df['col_c_LG'] = df['col_a'].str.extractall(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+LG)\b").unstack().apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Note you need to use a capturing group in the regex pattern so that [`extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) could actually extract the text:

> Extract **capture groups** in the regex *pat* as columns in a DataFrame.

Note the `\b` word boundary is necessary to match `PY` / `LG` as a whole word.

Also, if you want to only start a match from a letter, you may revamp the pattern to

```
r"([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z'-]*\s+PY)\b"
r"([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z'-]*\s+LG)\b"
   ^^^^^^^^          ^
```

where `[a-zA-Z]` will match a letter and `[a-zA-Z'-]*` will match 0 or more letters, apostrophes or hyphens.

Python 3.7 with Pandas 0.24.2:

```
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 500)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col_a': ['Python PY is a general-purpose language LG',
             'Programming language LG in Python PY',
             'Its easier LG to understand  PY',
             'The syntax of the language LG is clean PY',
             'Python PY is a general purpose PY language LG']
    })
df['col_b_PY'] = df['col_a'].str.extractall(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+PY)\b").unstack().apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
df['col_c_LG'] = df['col_a'].str.extractall(r"([a-zA-Z'-]+\s+LG)\b").unstack().apply(lambda x:' '.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
                                           col_a              col_b_PY     col_c_LG
0     Python PY is a general-purpose language LG             Python PY  language LG
1           Programming language LG in Python PY             Python PY  language LG
2                Its easier LG to understand  PY        understand  PY    easier LG
3      The syntax of the language LG is clean PY              clean PY  language LG
4  Python PY is a general purpose PY language LG  Python PY purpose PY  language LG
```

Comment: change the single quote to double quote ?

Answer (score 2):

Check with

```
df['col_c_LG'],df['col_c_PY']=df['col_a'].str.extract(r"(\w+\s+LG)"),df['col_a'].str.extract(r"(\w+\s+PY)")
df
Out[474]: 
                                        col_a       ...              col_c_PY
0  Python PY is a general-purpose language LG       ...             Python PY
1       Programming language LG in Python PY        ...             Python PY
2             Its easier LG to understand  PY       ...        understand  PY
3   The syntax of the language LG is clean PY       ...              clean PY
[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Thanks a ton! @Wen-Ben 
you came up with new  solutions and the whole answer

Comment: `Col_a`
          `Python PY is a general purpose PY language LG`
**in col_a contains PY is two times i need  to capture python py and purpose py
our regex paterrn capturing only one time**
          `output`
          `Python PY purpose PY`