# Finding keyword +1 and making new column

Tags: regex, pandas, text, nlp, keyword

**Goals:**

1) locate word next to keyword (e.g `brca`)

2) create a new column with this word

**Background:**

1) I have a list `l` in which I make into a dataframe `df` and extract the word `brca` from it using the following code:

```
l = ['carcinoma brca positive completion mastectomy',
     'clinical brca gene mutation',
     'carcinoma brca positive chemotherapy']
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Text'])
df['Gene'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(brca)")
```

**Output:**

```
                                                Text    Gene
0   breast invasive lobular carcinoma brca positiv...   brca
1   clinical history brca gene mutation . gross de...   brca
2   left breast invasive ductal carcinoma brca pos...   brca
```

**Problem:**

However, I am now trying to find the word next to the word `brca` for each row and create a new column.

**Desired Output:**

```
                                                Text    Gene  NextWord
0   breast invasive lobular carcinoma brca positiv...   brca  positive
1   clinical history brca gene mutation . gross de...   brca  gene
2   left breast invasive ductal carcinoma brca pos...   brca  positive
```

I have looked [python pandas dataframe words in context: get 3 words before and after](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41127321/python-pandas-dataframe-words-in-context-get-3-words-before-and-after) and [PANDAS Finding the exact word and before word in a column of string and append that new column in python (pandas) column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55223093/pandas-finding-the-exact-word-and-before-word-in-a-column-of-string-and-append-t) but they do not quite work for me.

**Question:**

How do I accomplish my goals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of the built-in method of python called [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html)

```
df['NextWord'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.partition('brca')[2]).str.split().str[0]
```

**Output**

```
                                            Text  Gene  NextWord
0  carcinoma brca positive completion mastectomy  brca  positive
1                    clinical brca gene mutation  brca      gene
2           carcinoma brca positive chemotherapy  brca  positive
```

**Explanation**

`.partition` returns three values:

- The string before the keyword
- The keyword itself
- The string after the keyword

```
string = 'carcinoma brca positive completion mastectomy'

before, keyword, after = string.partition('brca')

print(before)
print(keyword)
print(after)
```

**Output**

```
carcinoma 
brca
 positive completion mastectomy
```

---

## Speed

I was curious about the speed comparison between the answers, since I used `.apply` but its a built in method. Unexpectedly, my answer was the fastest:

```
dfbig = pd.concat([df]*10000, ignore_index=True)
dfbig.shape

(30000, 2)
```

```
%%timeit
dfbig['Text'].apply(lambda x: x.partition('brca')[2]).str.split().str[0]
31.5 ms ± 1.36 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
dfbig['NextWord'] = dfbig['Text'].str.split('brca').str[1].str.split('\s').str[1]
74.5 ms ± 2.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

%%timeit
dfbig['NextWord'] = dfbig['Text'].str.extract(r"(?<=brca)(.+?) ")
40.7 ms ± 2.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

With heavy use of the pandas `Series.str` accessor:

```
df['NextWord'] = df['Text'].str.split('brca').str[1].str.split('\s').str[1]
df

                                            Text  Gene  NextWord
0  carcinoma brca positive completion mastectomy  brca  positive
1                    clinical brca gene mutation  brca      gene
2           carcinoma brca positive chemotherapy  brca  positive
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
import pandas as pd

l = ['carcinoma brca positive completion mastectomy',
     'clinical brca gene mutation',
     'carcinoma brca positive chemotherapy']
df = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['Text'])

df['NextWord'] = df['Text'].str.extract(r"(?<=brca)(.+?) ")
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                            Text   NextWord
0  carcinoma brca positive completion mastectomy   positive
1                    clinical brca gene mutation       gene
2           carcinoma brca positive chemotherapy   positive
```